# User settings not being read in a different folder

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I'm scripting some program that uses user settings and are being set programatically but if I move the .exe file to another folder, settings won't be saved and the user will have to start over again. My question is how do I set it so it'll be saved even if the user moves the file to another location or even another PC?

Comment: I do not completely get it. Do you save the settings in the same folder as your application? If you want to save settings and load it from another PC, you need some kind of database server in your network, or use some kind of cloud drive.

Comment: When I move the file, the config file doesn't get created in the new path, but settings do save in the new path (without a new file). I want the settings to be local and be read the same even if the path is different.

Comment: The config file is not created automatically. And settings... maybe it is best to save/load it from the users AppData folder (create a subfolder in it first): `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`